# Date Manipulation in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

myDate = "2021-09-13T00:00:00"

now I try to create a date out of the sting

`new Date().setDate(new Date(options.startDate).getDate())`
which is `"2021-09-13T17:56:08-05:00"`

the problem here, somehow it uses my current time with the date, however I want to be able to set the time to either midnight or noon.

I looked at many posts here in Stackoverflow however no solution worked for me.

Any feedback, please?

Comment: You have a date with no timezone, so what timezone do you expect? UTC? The device's local for each user? What date is that actually supposed to be? You can't really say midnight or noon without specifying *where*.

Comment: Have you considered using a package like [dayjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs) for date manipulation? If you know what timezone you want the time in, there are also plugins that allow you to manipulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse a date and then change the hours (time) then you can use [setHours.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) This assumes you want to stay in local time.

To explicitly overwrite to an exact time, you can use the overloaded function:

```
setHours(hoursValue)
setHours(hoursValue, minutesValue)
setHours(hoursValue, minutesValue, secondsValue)
setHours(hoursValue, minutesValue, secondsValue, msValue) <-- this
```

Snippet:

```js
const myDate = "2021-09-13T00:00:00";

const parsedDate = new Date(myDate);
console.info(parsedDate.toString());

// set to 12pm
parsedDate.setHours(12, 00, 00, 00);
console.info(parsedDate.toString());

// set to midnight, which is essential next day
parsedDate.setHours(24, 00, 00, 00);
console.info(parsedDate.toString());
```